# I cant seem to get whats wrong with my code, I cant get the output

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement, syntax, conditional-operator

I have been writing this code of odd and even numbers using ternary operator but it is showing

```
"expected primary-expression before ‘?’ token"
```

My code:

```
{  
  int n;
  cout<<"enter any numbner::";
  cin>>n;

  if(n%2==0) ? cout<<"no is even::" : cout<<"no is odd::";

  return 0;
}
```

expected o/p is:

```
enter any number:20
no is even::
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a **mixure of** [if-statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) and [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) here:

```
  if (n % 2 == 0) ? cout << "no is even::" : cout << "no is odd::";
//^^^           ^^^^
```

which is wrong. You could write with conditional operator like

```
(n % 2 == 0) ? std::cout << "no is even::" : std::cout << "no is odd::";
```

or more compact

```
std::cout << ( n % 2 == 0 ? "no is even::" : "no is odd::" );
//           ^^                                           ^^
```

Note the extra parentheses, which is due to the higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) of arithmetic left shift `<<` than the conditional operator `a?b:c`.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up practices. A ternery (`?`) expects value to evaluate - `if` doesn't give a value.

Either do:

```
if(n%2==0) {
    cout<<"no is even::";
} else { 
    cout<<"no is odd::";
}
```

or

```
std::string value = (n%2) ? "odd" : "even";
cout << value;
// for bonus points you can do this without a temporary variable.
```